# How do I save a variable assigned to another variable?

Tags: vbscript, ibm-pcomm

I have this code to execute a command, and after I move to a certain row on the screen in a 3270 PCOM Host emulator with VBScript, I want to get the position of the current row, so I call:

```vb
'Save the current Line
LigneEnCours= autECLSession.autECLPS.CursorPosRow
```

Suppose that the cursor is now at row 7, so `LigneEnCours = 7`

After that I execute this code:

```
'Execute a command called 'My Command' that I put in line 24 column 12
autECLSession.autECLPS.SetText <My Command>, 24, 12
autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "[enter]"
```

When I call `autECLSession.autECLPS.SetText 'My Command', 24, 12`, the cursor moves to line 24 and column 12. So `autECLSession.autECLPS.CursorPosRow` returns 24.

After that I call this:

```
'Puting the cursor in the saved current line
 autECLSession.autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady 60
 autECLSession.autECLPS.SetCursorPos LigneEnCours, 2
```

At that moment, LigneEnCours contains 24 and not 7 as I expected.

Why, and how to solve that please?

Comment: `Constants` need to be declared before you run a script, you can't change them or set them during the run.  `LigneEnCours` should contain the value of your current row at the time you set it, regardless of what the session changes to.  Are the `**` supposed to be part of the code or are you trying to go for emphasis?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, the ** are just for code clarification.

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem with the code (ignoring the `**`s, I suggest you remove those as they're not needed)?

Comment: The problem is that I want to save the current position of the cursor, but my variable LigneEnCours point ok the new value of the autECLSession.autECLPS.CursorPosRow that is changing dynamically in the code

Comment: Try LigneEnCours = CInt(autECLSession.autECLPS.CursorPosRow) to make sure that LigneEnCours is really only a value. It should not change by itself if it is a value.

Comment: @NoualiYahya What are you using VBScript in?, for example, where does the `autECLSession` object come from? Is it a COM component or a specific hosted environment that gives you access to these objects? A little context would be useful.

Comment: Yes it is a specefic hosted environmeng from IBM

Answer (score -1):

Don't know about the rest but if this is regular vbscript and your `autECLSession.autECLPS` is the equivalent of `WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")` your sendkeys line has to be

```
autECLSession.autECLPS.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

EDIT: after your own edit: seems like your LigneEnCours contains an object and not a value, try Regis suggestion or something like `LigneEnCours = autECLSession.autECLPS.CursorPosRow * 1` or `LigneEnCours = "" & autECLSession.autECLPS.CursorPosRow`, whichever doesn't give an error

Comment: Thanks for your reply, no the problem is not there, the ENTER does work correctly. Maybe I have not explained my problem correctly. So I will try again.